# Asking query performance questions

Tags: discussion, faq, asking-questions

What information should be provided when asking how to improve the performance of a query?

Answer (score 27):

As many of the following as possible:

- [Formatted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) text of the query/procedure/function.

  - Indenting SQL by 4+ spaces on each line is usually best.
- Schema (CREATE TABLE); use text, not images

  - Table, index, and constraint definitions (scripts).
  - Even better:  A link to a **demo** that [reproduces the core of the problem](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2990).
- The [performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) or [query-optimization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) tag.
- [Query plans](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/796)

  - Ideally the post-execution variety, containing **runtime information**.
  - Estimated execution plans (if obtaining a post-execution plan is not practical).
  - *Anonymized* plans are acceptable but may limit answer quality.
  - A *picture* of execution is *occasionally* enough (but discouraged).
- Environment

  - Database product, precise **version**, and edition.
  - Hardware (e.g. **memory**/CPU/storage) and OS information.
- About the issue

  - What is the intent of the query
  - Current and desired performance levels.
  - Things you can and cannot change (e.g. can add indexes, cannot change the query).
  - The tuning steps followed so far.

#### Further reading

- [Slow Query Questions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions), [Using `EXPLAIN`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_EXPLAIN), [Performance Optimization](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) (PostgreSQL Wiki)
- [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE)
- [Help us help you : keys to getting good answers](https://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/).

Comment: I'm hoping to keep this answer to a manageable size. Please contribute, but prioritize brevity over comprehensiveness. Feel free to add additional links to the **Further reading** section at the end.

Comment: "Maneageable size" -- I added structure since there are only about 6 things.  I can answer most query performance questions given only the first 2.  (The 3rd, a tag, is to get my attention.)

Answer (score 6):

### Instructions for PostgreSQL Performance Questions

Copied from the [postgresql-performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-performance) [tag info](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

About improving / explaining the performance of existing queries. May concern particular query techniques or the setup of your hard- and software. Tag with [postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) as well.

Questions about *trivial* queries should rather go to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/). See [DBA Help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about suitable questions.

Consider basic advice on [Performance Optimization](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) and [Slow Query Questions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions) in the PostgreSQL Wiki, including the section "Things to try before you post". [`EXPLAIN`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_EXPLAIN) is particularly important.

#### When posting questions, include:

- Your [**Postgres version**](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), at least the major version like "15" or "9.6". (Since Postgres 10, the major version is just the leading number.) Find out with: `SELECT version();`
- Your **actual query** / queries. In a readable format and as brief as possible, but don't remove anything that might be relevant. Describe the expected result. Include an example for simple cases.
- **Table definition**(s): Preferably a `CREATE TABLE` script showing data types and constraints for relevant columns and `CREATE INDEX` scripts for relevant indexes. (The output from `\d+ tablename` in [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) is a less useful fallback.)
- **Cardinalities** (rough number of rows) in involved tables. Cardinalities (rough number of distinct values) and typical distribution in crucial columns.
- **Query plan**(s) obtained with **`EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE, SETTINGS)`**. (Before Postgres 12 just **`EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)`**.)
  Consider pasting plans on [explain.depesz.com](https://explain.depesz.com/), and include the resulting link.
- Link to an online demo at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) or similar, populated with the schema, some sample data, and the query.
- Only where relevant, a brief mention of your hardware and system, like: "CentOS 6.1, Xeon E5-2450 with 64GB RAM, 4-disk RAID 10 of Intel X-25E SSDs". Or more details if your question is about hardware.

Answer (score 3):

*<sub>Taken from a comment by [Wilson Hauck](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/56436/wilson-hauck) on a MySQL performance issue [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/274722/#comment538825_274722).</sub>*

## Instructions for MySQL Performance Questions

1. Computer specifications

   - RAM size
   - SSD/NVME versus HDD on MySQL Host server

   Please post on [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com) and share the links.  (Or similar product.)

Additionally from your SSH login root, text results of:

2. `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` (after minimum 24 hours UPTIME)
3. `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;`
4. `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`
5. a complete MySQLTuner report

   - Windows version: [github.com/pmachapman/mysqltuner](https://github.com/pmachapman/mysqltuner)
   - Linux version: [MySQLTuner-perl](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl)
6. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`
7. `SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name;`
   required for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.
8. Enable the mysql slow query log ([MySQL-5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html), [MySQL-8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html), [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/)). This can be done at runtime (in addition to the config file for next restart):

   - `SELECT @@slow_query_log_file, @@log_output;` to see what the filename (if `@@log_output` is FILE) will be. Change if required before enabling with `slow_query_log`.
   - `SELECT @@long_query_time;` to see what the time in seconds for the slow queries are. The default of 10 seconds is rarely useful; change to `1`.
   - `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log=1 /*M!100005 , GLOBAL log_slow_verbosity='query_plan,explain' */;`
   - use [mysqldumpslow -s t](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldumpslow.html) or [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html) to summarize the important ones.
   - Post the most important queries along with `EXPLAIN {query}` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for each table in the query.  (Please do not use the less-descriptive `DESCRIBE`.)
9. Please use text, not images.

Comment: You need also to post an EXPLAIN SELECT .... to see if and which indexes where used. Further a cull CREATE TABLE with INDEXES is qalso helpful.

Comment: @nbk You can add the details to the answer yourself. It's a ***community wiki*** answer and as such can be edited by anyone/everyone.